# Найти третье максимально число из трех целых чисел

Tags: c++, массивы

**Задача**: дано натуральное число n и целые числа a(1) , a(2) ... a(n). Без сортировки всего массива(работать с числами НЕ по возрастанию), найти третье максимальное число из тех целых чисел. При вводе ненатурального числа, вывести соответствующее послание. Должна быть возможность продолжить пользоваться программой, не выходя из нее.

**Сделал**: мне удалось написать программу, чтобы она находила максимальное число.

**Проблема**: как найти именно третье максимальное. Конечно, еще не уверен, что правильно выполнил пункт про сортировку.

```
   #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int ok;
        do{
            int N,i,Max;
            do{
            cout << "Введите n ( n >= 0): ";
            cin >> N;
            }while (N < 0);

            int a[N];
            for(i=0;i<N;i++)
            {
                cout << "Введите целое a (" << i << ")число: ";
                cin >> a[i];
            }
            Max = a[0];
            for(i=1;i<N;i++)
            {
            if(Max < a[i]) Max = a[i];
            }
            cout << "Максимальное число: " << Max << endl;
            cout << " Продолжить (1), закончить (0)?" << endl;
            cin >> ok;

            }while(ok==1);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n; // Вводим количество элементов.
    int a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> a[i]; // Вводим сами элементы.
    }

    int max1 = INT_MIN;
    int max2 = INT_MIN;
    int max3 = INT_MIN;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // Если число, которое встретили больше первого максимума, 
        // делаем текущий первый максимум вторым, 
        // второй третьим и перезаписываем первый максимум новым числом
        if (a[i] > max1) { max3 = max2; max2 = max1; max1 = a[i]; }

        // Если число, которое встретили меньше первого максимума, 
        // но больше второго, аналогично делаем текущий второй максимум третьим, 
        // а на место второго ставим текущий элемент массива
        else if (a[i] < max1 && a[i] > max2) { max3 = max2; max2 = a[i]; }

        // Аналогично с числом, которое больше третьего максимума, но меньше остальных
        else if (a[i] < max2 && a[i] > max3) { max3 = a[i]; }
    }

    cout << max1 << " " << max2 << " " <<max3;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! В четверг будет зачёт, думаю сдам !

Comment: Но можно проще.

Comment: А точно всегда работает? Что-то меня инициализация настораживает.

Comment: если первый максимальный - ничего хорошего не будет.

Comment: откуда INT_MIN ?

Comment: он что-то меняет ?

Comment: @Halfpizods выше люди подсказали, что если первый элемент массива - максимальный, то мы его запишем как max2 и max3, из-за чего все последующие элементы никогда не перезапишут эти значения. INT_MIN - константа, минимальное число которое может хранить int. Мы используем его, предпологая, что числа в массиве будут больше и перезапишут все переменные, хранящие максимумы

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>    
int main() {
    //...
    const size_t k = 3; //к  _ тый по счету максимальный элемент
    if (k <= N) {
        std::nth_element(a, a + k - 1, a + N, std::greater_equal<int>());
        std::cout << k << " - ий максмалный элемент " << a[k - 1];
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: в какой из циклов это нужно вставить?

Comment: ни в какой, это вся программа,  только сначала  правильно создайте и  инициализируйте свой  массив.

Comment: кажется мне такое решение не засчитают, мол "мы такого не проходили, как вы это сделали и тд." , так просто один раз уже было, в данный момент мы на теме динамических массивов и такого рода решение мы еще не трогали

Comment: скорее всего не засчитают. Я на это расчитывал когда писал, потому что за вас сделать задание неправильно. Возьмите 3 первые элемента: min1 = a[0], min2 = a[1], min3 = a[2],  остальные элементы сравните с этими. Если больше какого то из них, то выполняйте присваивание. Вы это сделали с одним, а теперь делайте для трех

Answer (score 2):

https://ideone.com/4Ztvo6

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a[] = { 4, 6, -1, 12, 0, -2, 7, 3 };
  int x = a[0], y = a[1], z = a[2];

  size_t n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;

  if (x > y) swap(x, y);
  if (x > z) swap(x, z);
  if (y > z) swap(y, z);

  for (size_t q=3; q<n; ++q)
    if (a[q] >= y)
    {
      x = y;

      if (a[q] > z)
        y = z, z = a[q];
      else
        y = a[q];
    }
    else if (a[q] > x)
      x = a[q];

  cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: опять такие вещи, которые мы еще не трогали, но я думаю мы их скоро возьмем, можно комментарии к коду?

Comment: Какие именно комментарии?

Comment: @Qwertiy я полагаю, что они еще не прошли `sizeof, swap, size_t` и вопросы сейчас по ним